# Infinite Trees, Infinite Branches, And Choice

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(set_theory)

Defines a tree T order-theoretically as a poset that has a minimum element R, and for each t in T, the set of lower bounds of T is well-ordered. This makes sense.

If I take the above definition and say "an infinite tree possesses an infinite branch", this is some kind of choice principle, right?

How does this relate to countable choice, dependent choice, and the axiom of choice? Is this principle something like dependent choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few unclear things with your question. What is an infinite tree? If you have just one level above the minimum, is the tree infinite? So we need to talk about height, the least ordinal strictly larger than all the levels of the tree. But even then we have a problem, since we can write down an example of a tree which has height $\omega$, but every node has finitely many successors, so there are no infinite branches.

Therefore we really want to say something like "a tree without leaves" (which will immediately imply the height is an infinite ordinal). And now we can actually talk about what guarantees a branch.

Dependent Choice is equivalent to the statement "Every tree without leaves has an infinite branch". In the one direction, just use Dependent Choice to produce a branch, the same as you would done in the usual case of $\sf ZFC$. In the other direction, if we have a non-empty set with a relation on it which satisfy the assumptions of Dependent Choice, then the finite sequences which satisfy the conclusion (i.e., consecutive nodes are related) form a tree without leaves, and a branch is a function witnessing the conclusion.

Note, however, that the above depends on how you define a branch. If you define a branch as a *maximal* chain, rather than just a chain, then "Every tree without nodes has a branch" is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice, as you can work out a proof that for every $\kappa$, Dependent Choice for sequences of length $\kappa$ holds. Which in turn imply the axiom of choice.

Comment: Is there a hidden assumption here that the tree is finitely branching?

Comment: No, that would be even less than countable choice.

Comment: Then why don't we get a counterexample by joining infinitely many linear branches of all finite heights at a single root node? Unless I'm confused, Dependent Choice would be "a tree with no leaves has an infinite branch", but we don't have a no-leaves assumption in this question.

Comment: Which is exactly why I wrote infinite height. But you're right that we need to be careful. I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: In that case I think I fail to understand what you take the "height" of the tree to be -- I assumed it would be the least upper bound of any node height (that is, $\omega$ in my example).

Comment: This is not correct as written, Asaf. How are you measuring height? You do not want to assign a rank to nodes by letting the height of $p $ be the first ordinal not a height of the predecessors of $p $, and then measure the height of the tree as the supremum of the successors of these ordinals: A tree of height $\omega $ under this definition does not have to have infinite branches, and a tree of height past $\omega $ trivially has infinite (not necessarily cofinal) branches. Do you perhaps mean an ill-founded tree?

Comment: @Andres: Trees grow up! :-)

Comment: @Henning: Is this better now?

Comment: @Asaf, yes. :-)

Comment: The last paragraph has me slightly confused.

Comment: @John: Can you be a bit more specific as to what confused you?

Comment: @Asaf: So "every tree without leaves has an infinite chain" is equivalent to DC and "every tree without leaves has an infinite maximal chain" is equivalent to AC?

Comment: @John: Trees can be very tall.

Comment: So what's the difference between: "for every κ, Dependent Choice for sequences of length κ holds", and Dependent Choice itself?

Comment: That Dependent Choice only talks about sequences of type $\omega$. And that's not even enough to construct an injection from $\omega_1$ into the real numbers.